# Which would be the proper SE site to ask a question about a computer scanner issue?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have noticed that sometimes when I scan a negative, the scan has light and dark horizontal stripes around the edges of objects in the image. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong when I make the scan, and if there's a way to avoid ending up with stripes in the image.

Below is a screenshot of a scan blown up 600%.

[image: screenshot of scan]

The screenshot is of a scan made on a Epson V600 scanner. It was sharpened afterward in Photoshop 7.

Please direct me to the proper SE site to ask a question about a computer scanner issue.

Answer (score 2):

As [PeterJames](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1242908/peterjames) mentioned, it's on-topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). See the [scanning tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scanning).  Example of a similar question: [How can I improve the scan quality of the text written with a pencil?](https://superuser.com/q/1691192/116475)